# Making div scrollable under a div with variable height

Tags: html, css

I have a page as follows:

[image]

Component A has a variable height, so during the session it is changing according to the inputs of user.

Component B has a large (thus ***unknown***) height, so i need a scrollbar (most of the time).

What would the best solution be to present such a page, ***only using css***?

*ps: i don't want to use new attributes like flex-grow or flex-shrink due to their compatibility issues.*

Comment: Component A possible to  max-height limit ?

Comment: if I understand right, `overflow-y: scroll` will do this!

Comment: @LaljiTadhani yes it is known.

Comment: @pedram without knowing the exact height of component B, it does not work

Comment: but you can set a `min-height` like `min-height: 200px`

Comment: `min-height` doesn't help to activate overflow

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you should use css, because you can also use conditional css for div like max-height:300px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;

It means if div height increase then 300px then scroll will show there.

Answer (score 0):

add Component B  `max-height`  like

```
.ComponentB
 {
   max-height:calc(100% - 200px);
   overflow:auto;
 }
```

Comment: how can i write this part `- componet A Height);` for a div with id `compA` ? i could not find

Comment: 'componet A Height'  means fix height ex. '200px'

Comment: But as i said, height of component A is variable, not fixed.

Comment: Component A possible to max-height limit ?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani yes it is known.

Comment: try to with jquery

Comment: max-height, thus the maximum number the div can reach. It does not mean we can assign a fixed height instead of its actual height.

Answer (score 0):

Your means component A and component B both has a unknow height;But A has 
a ***min-height*** ,B has a ***max-height*** ,I write a demo as follow.

```css
.A {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.B {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="A"></div>
<textarea class="B"></textarea>
```